# How can I assign multiple values to a Hashtable with separate chaining?

Tags: c, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable, collision

so I'm trying to gain a better understanding of Hashtables in C. One common problem I heard is collisions where the same name, word, value, whatever gets assigned the same hash as another value. I wanted to learn the separate chaining method from [this code](https://gist.github.com/kuriringohankamehameha/fceee2e3c126f37fd254ee0acf2b4633) I found on github, but I am having trouble understanding something.

When I run the code I get this output, which seems correct:

```
Key:1, Value:First address
Key:2, Value:Second address
3 does not exist
Key: Hel, Value:Third address
Key:Cau, Value:Fourth address

-----------------------------
Index:49, Key:1, Value:First address
Index:50, Key:2, Value:Second address
Index:281, Key:Hel, Value:Third address => Overflow Bucket => Key:Cau, Value;Fourth address
-----------------------------

-----------------------------
Index:50, Key:2, Value:Second address
Index:281, Key:Hel, Value:Third address
```

But something I'm not understanding is how to implement multiple values to be stored within the hashtable.

The point I'm making is I want to have two things, such as

- Ice Cream flavor ("chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry") and type of container ("bowl", "waffle cone", "regular cone")
  or
- Sequential word pairs ("the" and "guy"), ("major" and "pain"), ("good" and "job") from a file or input
  or
- Maybe I want to have three values tied together like Gender, Name and age ("Cau", "27", "Male") , ("Hel", "29", "Female"), ("Alex", "38", "Male)

I am just not sure how to even begin doing this. I know we use a hash function to map a key (being any input) to a value. I know we can use separate chaining by utilizing linked lists to avoid collisions. But in the context of this code, or better yet in general, how can we have multiple keys that we want associated with eachother, such as a word pair, or ice cream and it's container, or a person's name with their age and gender, and assign it to the same value / hash bucket and store it together?

I already have a function that generates a hash. It creates some incredibly large number and I modulus it by 6 so I get values like 4, 9, 38, 12, 2, 5. I'm aiming to implement Something like

```
Key: {"1", "one"}, Value: 4
Key: {"2", "two"}, Value: 9 => Key: {"3", "three"}, Value: 9 // Collision occurs here
```

or

```
Key: {"good", "job"}, Value: 38
Key: {"keep", "trying"}, Value: 12 => Key: {"go", "ahead"}, Value: 12 // Collision occurs here
Key: {"don't", "stop"}, Value: 4
```

or

```
Key: {"strawberry", "bowl"}, Value: 2
Key: {"vanilla", "waffle cone"}, Value: 5
Key: {"vanilla", "regular cone"}, Value: 14
```

What are some ways I can do this?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with hash collisions. Sounds more like you're talking about wanting to store structs in the table.

Comment: _how can we have multiple keys that we want associated with each other, such as a word pair, or ice cream and it's container, or a person's name with their age and gender, and assign it to the same value / hash bucket and store it together?_ Isn't this just a `struct`? (e.g.) `struct person { char name[100]; int age; int gender; };`

Comment: Yes sorry I should have been more clear. I want to generate a value with my Key being the struct containing two items.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer to my own question. My lack of knowledge regarding C prevented me from seeing the obvious solution:

within the code segment:

```
struct Ht_item {
    char* key;
    char* value;
};
```

I could just declare a new char pointer for a second key:

```
struct Ht_item {
    char* key;
    char* key2;
    char* value;
);
```

and perform the same variety of functions that were done with the key value. I think what tripped me up is that the `item` struct is only working on key and value within the code and was under the presumption this cannot be altered or it would affect functionality. Adding the key2 makes no difference since anything in the `Ht_item` struct can be acted upon for the variety of operations written. Freed, inserted, searched, printed, whatever.